# Problem with email confirmation on my nodejs server deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I deployed my node.js server on Heroku and I have a problem with email confirmation :

This is my server-side code responsible to retrieve a token from URL and set the key `isEmailConfirmed: true` in my MongoDB

```
app.get("/emailconfirmtoken/:token", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.token) {
      const token = req.params.token;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { token: token },
        { $set: { isEmailConfirmed: true } },
        { new: true }
      )
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
          if (result) {
            res.redirect("https://awesomepage.com/");
          }
        });
    }
  });
```

This is how it looks on my local machine

[localServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4swRG.jpg)

[localDatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZa1B.jpg)

BUT if I try to do the same in my node.js server deployed in Heroku :

[Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOgSK.jpg)

Unfortunately, I have `isEmailConfirmed: false`

[database false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2GVu.jpg)

Is there anyone who faced the same problem?

I really have no idea why locally I can confirm my email address but on my node server on production, I can't do that? Is it possible that Heroku blocks something?

Please help !!

Thanks for all your answers have a good day.

Comment: Where is your MongoDB hosted? How do you connect it from Heroku ?

Comment: My MongoDB is hosted on cloud MongoDB atlas. This is how I connect it from heroku : const mongoose = require("mongoose"); const { dbPass } = require("../config/security"); mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false); const connection = mongoose .connect( `mongodb+srv://awesomeDb:${dbPass}@cluster0-aikk5.mongodb.net/gamer?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, { useNewUrlParser: true } ) .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB")) .catch(err => { console.log(err); process.exit(); }); module.exports = { connection };.

Comment: Problem solved.